# Array initialization: a value of type "char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "float"

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point

I need to plot floating point values through cross core embedded studio but I see error in compilation

```
float ecgin[4]={"1011.0f,1011.0f,1011.0f"};

printf("%f\n",ecgin);
```

I see follwoing error when I try to compile the program

```
 cc0144:  error: a value of type "char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "float"
```

Comment: Why do you think `printf` will plot anything?

Comment: What output did you expect?

Answer (score 3):

First of all remove `" "` from brace-enclosed lists of array initialization. like :

```
float ecgin[4]={1011.0f,1011.0f,1011.0f};
```

instead of

```
float ecgin[4]={"1011.0f,1011.0f,1011.0f"};
```

And print the particular array element using an index. like :

```
printf("%f\n",ecgin[0]);
```

Comment: I need to plot the floating values of the ecg on the plot window in cross core embedded studio which i previously also  plotted in matlab

Comment: Still I get the same error when I try to remove the quotes from the floating numbers

Comment: @Fahad Shaikh See here : http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/sqAM4m

Comment: @FahadShaikh that cannot be true. Either removed something somewhere else instead of the mentioned array, or you got a different error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! My problem solved . Actually there was an error with the spacing between integers and when I remove the spacing, the problem solved